# Match street number from different formats without suffixes

Tags: regex, pcre

We've a "street_number" field which has been freely filed over the years that we want to format. Using regular expressions, we'd like to to extract the real "street_number", and the "street_number_suffix".

Ex: `17 b`, "street_number" would be `17`, and "street_number_suffix" would be `b`.

As there's a dozen of different patterns, I'm having troubles to tune the regular expression correctly. I consider using 2 different regexes, one to extract the "street_number", and another to extract the "street_number_suffix"

Here's an exhaustive set of patterns we'd like to format and the expected output:

```
# Extract street_number using PCRE

input           street_number   street_number_suffix

19-21           19              null
2 G             2               G
A               null            A
1 bis           1               bis
3 C             3               C
N°10            10              null
17 b            17              b
76 B            76              B
7 ter           7               ter
9/11            9               null
21.3            21              3
42              42              null
```

I know I could invoke an expressions that matches *any digits until a hyphen* using `\d+(?=\-)`.
It could be extended to match *until a hyphen OR a slash* using `\d+(?=\-|\/)`, thought, once I include `\s` to this pattern, `21` from `19-21` will match. Adding conditions may no be that simple, which is why I ask your help.

Could anyone give me a helping hand on this ? If it can help, here's a draft: https://regex101.com/r/jGK5Sa/4

---

Edit: at the time I'm editing, here's the closest regex I could find:

```
(?:(N°|(?<!\-|\/|\.|[a-z]|.{1})))\d+
```

Thought the full match of `N°10` isn't `10` but `N°10` (and our ETL doesn't support capturing groups, so I can't use `/......(\d+)/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the street numbers, you could update the pattern to:

```
(?<![-/.a-z\d])\d+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind

  - `[-/.a-z\d]` Match any of the listed using a charater class
- `)` Close the negative lookbehind
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0J3QT/1)

Comment: I love that your suggestion fits my need in a way simpler way than mines. Thanks a lot, I'm learning from it ! I'll write the second regex on my own tonight or tomorrow and update my post